# Get SoapUI version at runtime

Tags: groovy, soapui

How can I get the SoapUI version on which the test case was run with Groovy script?
I need to log by policy how the testing was executed, including the software used to run the test cases.

Something similar to this to get Java version:

```
String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version")
// Set something like "11.0.12"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/5.5.0/com/eviware/soapui/SoapUI.html#SOAPUI_VERSION

```
log.info('version: '+com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.SOAPUI_VERSION)
```

output:

```
INFO:version: 5.5.0
```